# How do I decode mail header strings with their encoding type in them in PHP

Tags: php, utf-8, iso-8859-1, decoding

I'm creating a small, web based, mail client in PHP and noticed that a number of email Subjects and Contents appear as follows:

```
=?ISO-8859-1?Q?Everything_for_=A35_-_Box_Sets,_Games_?= =?ISO-8859-1?Q?and_CD_Soundtracks...hurry,_ends_soon?=
=?utf-8?B?UGxheS5jb206IE9uZSBEYXkgT25seSDigJMgT3V0IG9mIHRoaXMgV29ybGQgRGVhbHMh?=
=?windows-1252?Q?Jon,_delivery_on_us_&_earn_=A35_credit_or_50_prints?=
```

Does anyone have any ideas for decoding them so they display correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an [RFC 2047](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047) encoded-word. It is decoded by the `mb_decode_mimeheader` function.

Comment: I was pointed here because of a possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41894171/google-apps-office-365-imap-from-name-character-set-encoding-how-to-decode-i).

If you're using IMAP then use `imap_utf8()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

This is MIME-encoded string mainly used for headers. You can find lots of libraries that can handle this. For example, get PEAR::mail and use this function,

```
Mail_mimeDecode::_decodeHeader()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but recently I came across this issue while parsing the emails.
When printing the header info using function [imap_header_info](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-headerinfo.php), the following array was shown:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [subject] => =?Windows-1252?Q?field_name_-_need___`at_risk=92____into_t?= =?Windows-1252?Q?he_label_(_some_content_to_)_?=
)
```

However, the original subject was "**field name - need at risk into the label (some content to)**"

In order to fix this issue, the function [imap_mime_header_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-mime-header-decode.php)
has to be used within a loop to generate the correct text:

```
$header = imap_headerinfo($email_obj, $email_ref_number, 0);
$elements = imap_mime_header_decode($header->subject);
$email_subject = '';
if ( ! empty($elements)) {
    foreach ($elements AS $e_part) {
        if (isset($e_part->text)) {
            $email_subject .= $e_part->text;
        }
    }
}
echo $email_subject;
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer. `mb_decode_mimeheader` does not handle underscores correctly and does not replace them with spaces