# =?ISO-8859-1 in mail subject

Tags: php, encoding, decoding

I'm acquiring the unread mails I have in my GMail account through PHP and its method *imap_open*

When I get the subjects through the method *imap_fetch_overview* I get some subjects like this:

```
=?ISO-8859-1?Q?Informaci=F3n_Apartamento_a_la_Venta?= =?ISO-8859-1?Q?_en_Benasque(Demandas:_0442_______)?=
```

It's unreadable, I think because of its character encoding.

What should I do to make it readable?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I decode mail header strings with their encoding type in them in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722451/how-do-i-decode-mail-header-strings-with-their-encoding-type-in-them-in-php)

Comment: Yes, it's the same problem. I will post an answer ellaborating more the solution. I will not delete the question because I think the title describes better the problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To get the string in UTF-8, do:

```
$or = '=?ISO-8859-1?Q?Informaci=F3n_Apartamento_a_la_Venta?= =?ISO-8859-1?Q?_en_Benasque(Demandas:_0442_______)?=';
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
$v = str_replace("_"," ", mb_decode_mimeheader($or));
```

which gives:

```
Información Apartamento a la Venta en Benasque(Demandas: 0442       )
```

You can then [convert](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) to ISO-8859-1, if you wish.

Comment: Thanks, that solves the character enconding thing and the underscores problem.

Answer (score -3):

```
$or = '=?ISO-8859-1?Q?Informaci=F3n_Apartamento_a_la_Venta?= =?ISO-8859-1?Q?_en_Benasque(Demandas:_0442_______)?=';
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
$v = str_replace("_"," ", mb_decode_mimeheader($or));
```

it works for me (thanks artefacto)

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3469111/208273)