# Attachments change name and type in SAP B1

Tags: smtp, sapb1

We are supporting a SAP B1 system and upon changing servers a while back some of the sent mails are getting weird.

When they receive at the customers mailbox the Attachment that when sent was named "Utgående_faktura_123456_20190311_085342.pdf" have changed name to "Bilaga utan namn 00008.dat", so both filetype and name is mixed up. "Bilaga utan namn" is swedish for "attachment without name", but i can't find when this change happens.

This only occurs for some of the customers and for one of them it even arrived correct once.

My guess is that it has something to do with the swedish character in the filename, the "å", but it seems to handle it correctly in the mails:

Correctly arrived mail:

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream;
name="=?iso-8859-1?Q?Utg=E5ende_faktura=5F701754=5F20190304=5F154624.pdf?="
Content-Description:=?iso-8859-1?Q?Utg=E5ende_faktura=5F701754=5F20190304=5F154624.pdf?=
Content-Disposition: attachment;
filename="=?iso-8859-1?Q?Utg=E5ende_faktura=5F701754=5F20190304=5F154624.pdf?=";
size=59659; creation-date="Mon, 04 Mar 2019 14:49:02 GMT";
modification-date="Mon, 04 Mar 2019 14:49:02 GMT"
```

Messed up mail:

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name="Bifogad fil utan namn 00009.dat"
Content-Description: Bifogad fil utan namn 00009.dat
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Bifogad fil utan namn 00009.dat";
size=59659; creation-date="Tue, 05 Mar 2019 07:20:50 GMT";
modification-date="Tue, 05 Mar 2019 07:20:50 GMT"
```

I have played around with Swedish/English settings without solution.

I'm starting to think this is related to [=?ISO-8859-1 in mail subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468849/iso-8859-1-in-mail-subject)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

​Root Cause: When the filename contains å, ä or ö it is encoded with ISO8859-1 by the smtp server. If the filename contains an underscore, _, it is errorunous encoded by the smtp-server.

If it is errorunous encoded some smtp-servers, on the receiving side, gives an error and names it "Attachment without name" and changes type to .dat.

Our solution was to change outgoing smtp-server.