# How to decode utf-8 from imap gmail

Tags: php, gmail, imap

I get this text from imap

> =?UTF-8?Q?Ho=C3=A0ng_V=C5=A9_H=C3=A0?=

When I tried with **imap_urf8($string)** and I got

> Hoà€ng Vùƒ Hà€

When I tried with **utf8_decode(imap_urf8($string))** and I got

> Hoa?ng Vu? Ha?

I want to get

> Hoàng Vũ Hà

How can I do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I decode mail header strings with their encoding type in them in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722451/how-do-i-decode-mail-header-strings-with-their-encoding-type-in-them-in-php)

Answer (score -3):

Try to use the search function. This is RFC 2047 encoding, and there's plenty of questions on how to decode that already here on SO.